# Find pair of indices given coordinates and values

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization

I have a question as below. I know the O(n^2) solution using 2 loops but is there a solution to solve it in linear time?

Given coordinates x as `x1, x2....,xn` and value p associated with each coordinate as `p1, p2,...,pn`, find the indices `(i,j)` such that `pi + pj + |xj - xi|` is maximum where `|x|` is absolute value.

Ex:

```
(x1, p1) = (5, 10)
(x2, p2) = (3, 20)
(x3, p3) = (12, 5)
The answer is (2,3).
```

Comment: O(n) is quite eager. I would be happy to even find an O(n logn) algorithm.

Comment: I think there should be some O(n logn) solution. The intuition is: sort the list of pairs <xk, pk> in a way so that the index `i` and `j` will be in the beginning and end of the list (after the sort).

Answer (score 0):

We can find O(n) solution if we observe the following:

- if `(i, j)` is the indices where `pi - xi` is maximum and `pj + xj` is maximum, then, the `(i, j)` is the very indices where `pi + pj + |xj - xi|` is maximum

---

**Proof**: Since `pi + pj + |xj - xi|` is equal to `(pi - xi) + (pj + xj)` or `(pj - xj) + (pi + xi)`, and `(pj - xj) + (pi + xi)` is changed to `(pi - xi) + (pj + xj)` when we interchange `i` and `j`, the maximum value of `pi + pj + |xj - xi|` is less than or equal to the maximum value of `(pi - xi) + (pj + xj)`. So now it suffices to show that `(pi - xi) + (pj + xj)` is equal to `pi + pj + |xj - xi|` when `(pi - xi)` is maximum and `(pj + xj)` is maximum and, hence, `(pi - xi) + (pj + xj)` is maximum. If `pi - xi` is maximum and `pj + xj` is maximum, `(pi - xi) + (pj + xj)` is maximum. And also `xj - xi >= 0` holds. (Otherwise, if `xj - xi < 0`, `(pi - xi) + (pj + xj) < (pj - xj) + (pi + xi)` so `pi - xi < pj - xj` or `pj + xj < pi + xi` which contradicts that `pi - xi` and `pj + xj` is maximum.) Hence, `(pi - xi) + (pj + xj) = pi + pj + |xj - xi|` and the `(i, j)` is the indices which maximize it.

---

So, in order to maximize `pi + pj + |xj - xi|`, we just need to find the indices `(i, j)` which maximize `pi - xi` and `pj + xj` respectively.

It is trivial that

- the index `i` which maximizes `pi - xi` can be found in O(n)
- the index `j` which maximizes `pj + xj` can be found in O(n)

Therefore, the indices `(i, j`) which is the answer can be found in O(n) + O(n) = O(n).

The full solution written in python is below. (It also seems that you assume `i != j`, because, otherwise, the example answer would be `(2, 2)`, not `(2, 3)`. So some code to make sure that `i != j` was added.)

```py
# Time complexity: O(n) where n is len(t_p) or len(t_x)
def get_argmax(t_p, t_x, operator, excluded_index=None):
    max = -float('inf')
    argmax = None
    for i, (p, x) in enumerate(zip(t_p, t_x)):
        if i == excluded_index:
            continue
        if operator(p, x) > max:
            max = operator(p, x)
            argmax = i
    return argmax


# get the answer indices (i, j)
# which maximizes t_p[i] + t_p[j] + |t_x[j] - t_x[i]|
# in time complexity O(n) where n is len(t_x) or len(t_p)
def get_answer(t_x, t_p):
    argmax_i = get_argmax(t_p, t_x, lambda a, b: a - b)  # O(n)
    argmax_j = get_argmax(t_p, t_x, lambda a, b: a + b)  # O(n)
    answer = (argmax_i, argmax_j)

    # The if statement below is for to make sure that argmax_i != argmax_j
    if argmax_i == argmax_j:
        second_argmax_i = get_argmax(t_p, t_x,
                                     lambda a, b: a - b, argmax_i)  # O(n)
        second_argmax_j = get_argmax(t_p, t_x,
                                     lambda a, b: a + b, argmax_j)  # O(n)
        max1 = (t_p[argmax_i] - t_x[argmax_i]) + (t_p[second_argmax_j] +
                                                  t_x[second_argmax_j])
        max2 = (t_p[second_argmax_i] - t_x[second_argmax_i]) + (t_p[argmax_j] +
                                                                t_x[argmax_j])
        if max1 >= max2:
            answer = (argmax_i, second_argmax_j)
        else:
            answer = (second_argmax_i, argmax_j)

    return answer


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t_x = [5, 3, 12]
    t_p = [10, 20, 5]

    answer = get_answer(t_x, t_p)

    answer_one_based_index = (answer[0] + 1, answer[1] + 1)
    print(f'The answer is {answer_one_based_index}.')
```

It prints:

```
The answer is (2, 3).
```

Comment: I think you need to maximise |pi - xi| instead of just pi-xi.

Comment: @maddy Could you tell me the reason? In my post, I explained that, to maximize `pi + pj + |xj - xi|`, it is just ***enough*** to maximize `pi + pj + xj - xi` which is equal to `(pj + xj) + (pi - xi)`. So we just need to maximize `pj + xj` and `pi - xi`, respectively.

Comment: @maddy After reading my post again, I realized that my writing was not that easy to understand. So I have enhanced the writing so that it is to be clearer than before. Thank you for your comment!